# Как остановить Task<V>

Tags: java, javafx

Как остановить этот поток?

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>(){
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        double TimeStart = 0d;
        for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
            TimeStart = TimeStart + 0.01;
            updateProgress(TimeStart, 1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(normalTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
  };
          time.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
          Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(task);
```

Comment: `cancel(true)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать [`cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel--%28%29) метод:

```
task.cancel(true);
```

В `Task` выход добавьте в обработчике исключений:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>(){
@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {
    double TimeStart = 0d;
    for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
        TimeStart = TimeStart + 0.01;
        updateProgress(TimeStart, 1);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(normalTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
};
```

Comment: Я попробовал, но ProgressIndicator всё ещё обновляется

Comment: @dhred В `Task` выход добавьте в обработчике исключений

Comment: Я понимаю, что это глупый вопрос, но как это сделать?

Comment: @dhred я обновил ответ, `return null;` в `catch` блоке добавьте

Comment: Получилось, но как его теперь снова запустить?

Comment: @dhred да вроде никак. Только заново через `new` создавать.

Comment: Всё равно спасибо огромное. Вряд ли бы я нашел решение без вас